# Получение содержимого текста в body

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, сервис сокращения ссылок, сделал такую функцию:
http://sulx.ru/shortme/api/apikey=0&url=https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started
Как вытащить от туда ссылку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А не проще это сделать в виде AJAX запроса и получить в ответ эту ссылку в виде JSON'a. `{"shortUrl": "http://sulx.ru/0fa2af6b"}`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://sulx.ru/shortme/api/",
    method: 'POST',
    data: {apikey: 0, url: "https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started"}
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data.shortUrl);
}).fail(function(dataError){
    console.log(dataError);
});
```

Comment: Ошибку выводит с таким запросом

Comment: Я без понятия на каком языке у Вас бекенд и мало того какую ошибку?

Comment: Оно не понимает, что такое `shortUrl`!

Comment: Вы объект отправляете в ответ или просто тоже что и было?

Answer (score 1):

document.body.innerHTML вернет тебе текст из body